# Tell if Facebook page redirects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, facebook-page

I've noticed that some facebook pages redirect.  For example the NOFX band page (http://www.facebook.com/pages/NOFX/104336479603261 only two links allowed so that one isn't set to link) redirects to their official page ( https://www.facebook.com/pages/NOFX-Official-Page/180985116576?rf=104336479603261 ).  I'm curious is if in the api we can tell that a page does this.  https://graph.facebook.com/104336479603261 doesn't seem to show anything about the redirect but, perhaps there's another way to find it.

Edit:
Solutions that don't use the api are fine.

Edit2:
Solved here is the code I used if anyone is interested:

Code mostly copied from [How can I determine if a URL redirects in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427203/how-can-i-determine-if-a-url-redirects-in-php).

```
function getURL($URL)
{
        $ch = curl_init($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3'); 
        curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $code;
}
```

Only thing really worth noting is that I had to add user agent so I don't get sent to an unsupported browser page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be exposed via the API or FQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Edit: Solutions that don't use the api are fine.

Then just make an HTTP HEAD request for the page URL, and see if you get a `301 Moved Permanently` status code with a `Location` header in response. (Actually checking the status code only should be enough, if you only want to find out *if* the page gets redirected; if you also want to know *where* it’s getting redirected to, then check the location header as well.)