# How to check if a link is redirecting to a specific link in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a link which I want to check if it is redirecting to the correct page or not, and if not then I have to display an error message.
For example, if my link is

`http://www.example.com/redirect.php?x=something`

then I will display the error message only when it is redirected to the following link:

`http://www.example3.com/`

otherwise it's okay and there's no need to display the error message. My script looks like:

```
$url=urldecode($_GET['l']);
$handle=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
$response=curl_exec($handle);
$httpCode=curl_getinfo($handle,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if(($httpCode==301)||($httpCode==302))
    echo 1;
curl_close($handle);
```

This code just tells whether the URL is redirected or not and does not tell where the URL is being redirected.

Comment: your question is a bit hard to understand... why don't you provide a bit of code, so we can use that code to understand the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Hallur edited.

Comment: Am I correct to assume, that the url is acquired by the get variable l? you could use a simple if statement, or a select case, or in_array, to check if l lives up to a certain condition??

Comment: @Hallur Yes, that assumption is correct but how to check the address where that $url is getting redirected?

Comment: oh, I see.. you're trying to check the redirection outside of your own server. Now I understand the question, but I don't know how to answer the question, however, I will do some research, as this is an interesting question indeed.

Comment: @Hallur yes, you got that correctly.

Comment: Read the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427203/how-can-i-determine-if-a-url-redirects-in-php the answer by earino should be taken into account. if javascript redirects, your code may not even see it.